# animation on jquery broken

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me correct my script: http://jsfiddle.net/b36cM/

```
                if(direction == -1){
                    wrapperElements.children(':last').after($('#carousel > ul').children().slice(0, options.rotateBy).clone());

                    shiftAction();

                    wrapperElements.children().slice(0, options.rotateBy).remove();
                }
                else{
                    // wrapperElements.children(':first').after($('#carousel > ul').children().slice(carouselLength - options.rotateBy, carouselLength).clone());

                    // shiftAction();

                    // wrapperElements.children().slice(carouselLength - options.rotateBy, carouselLength).remove();
                }               
            }

            function shiftAction(){
                console.log(offset);

                wrapperElements.animate({
                    'left': offset                  
                }, options.speed,   function(){
                                        running = false;
                                    });                 
            }               
        }
```

When clicked on `#prev` the animation shifts two elements to the left. I would like to scroll only one item, smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention that shiftAction() and remove() run asynchronous so animation not finished when element removed and that make you animation to jump on first element  you can check  it with

```
setTimeout(function() {
      wrapperElements.children().slice(0, options.rotateBy).remove();
       },5000);
```

but its not resolve the hole problem with animation